# What programming language are the % characters in URLs?

Tags: url, url-encoding

Just curious what language these characters in a URL are from?

For example:`force_name=1&name=Tom%20` which is a space.

Answer (score 6):

The `%` characters in URLs are not a "programming language."   Rather they are [URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or just [Percent Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). They allow characters to be used in URLs that that cannot otherwise be used un-escaped.

`%20` is a space because 20 is the ASCII code for a space character.  A space cannot be used in a URL un-escaped because not one of the characters listed as being allowed in URLs.

Percent encoding is defined in [section 2.1 of RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).